# React Native how to set the time and date as the local device?

Tags: react-native

I was trying to get the time and date and set as the local device format .

I have tried this api "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-time-format?activeTab=readme",

But dosen't work at all ..

Here is my code ,could you please take a look ?
Thank you so much ?

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { is24HourFormat } from 'react-native-device-time-format';
import moment from 'moment';

function TryTime(props) {
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState("");

    const getCurrentHourFormat = async (date) => {
        const is24Hour = await is24HourFormat();
        return moment(date).format(is24Hour ? 'HH:mm' : 'h:mm A');
      }

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const timeNow = await TryTime(Date.now);
            setCurrentTime(getCurrentHourFormat(timeNow));
        })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>{currentTime}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        flex : 1,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems : 'center',
    }
})
export default TryTime;
```

Comment: Do you mean ```new Date().toLocaleString()```?

Comment: Hey my friend ,thank you sooo much !! It is really cool ,however ,it seems very details.. Do you know how to get  more simple ? Something like 1 sec ago ,10 min ago ,1 hour ago ?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get the local time of device by JS, you can use a built-in function of js: `toLocaleString()`
Note:

For this question: *Do you know how to get more simple ? Something like 1 sec ago ,10 min ago ,1 hour ago*

=> i guess you have the previous date time, and you want to compare it to current time

something like:

```
a = ... // your previous time
b = new Date().toLocaleString()
```

Just take `let c = b - a` as the difference between 2 date, then

```
c / 1000 => get seconds
c / 1000 * 60 => get minutes
c / 1000 * 3600 => get hours
```